# What would a universe without relativity be like?

Tags: science-based, alien-geometry

Our Intrepid Researcher has fallen down the rabbit's wormhole, and found herself in a Strange New World.

While attempting to determine the local force of gravity, she notices that her gold (plated) pocketwatch has taken on a distinct [white color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_quantum_chemistry#Color_of_gold_and_caesium); similarly, the old-fashioned mercury thermometer in her lab coat now contains a [useless lump of silver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_quantum_chemistry#Mercury).

What other human-scale impacts might she notice thanks to the lack of relativity in this universe once she goes looking for them? We'll assume for now that anything that would horrifically break reality to the point where life cannot exist is smoothed over by magic.

Comment: So what is relativity replaced with? Does the world just function on Newtonian physics?

Comment: Well done in giving examples of how specific metals would be changed by non-relativistic quantum chemistry. You can assume that c is a simply a constant in all the physics equation where it appears. Since you are asking about human-scale changes, as opposed to wider cosmological changes, this would require examining aspects of everyday life to see how they might be changed in the absence of relativity. Oh yes, no GPS and no perihelion of the planet Mercury.

Comment: You mean Einsteinian relativity, obviously. Absence of Galilean relativity would make for an _extremely_ strange world.

Comment: See https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30208/effective-way-to-recreate-a-magnetosphere-on-mars-with-current-technology and also see https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/74777/re-working-physics-for-a-newtonian-universe